Why blender adds a Key rotation on my armature after FBX export? Why my retargeted maximo character is messed up after a FBX export?
I am doing some FBX export and re-targeting and getting some weird issues

After I export my human model in T-pose as FBX, I am getting a slight key rotation added onto my character's armature onto the X rotation ,it happens every time.


https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hni4nfbvElB9WDQbqGI3R0dUA-XCLcXI/view?usp=drive_link

When going through the Mixamo re-targeting process with their add-on, everything goes OK, but after I export my animation as a FBX, the character is mega-jumping on XYZ at each frame (despite the animation being there too)


https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KA8TAk_xsRE0G9SMJGAqV-8fH-zoY8BW/view?usp=drive_link

thanks for helping editing !
